# Resetting an encoding back to null in Altair

Tags: python, plot, altair

I have a chart `c2` that is derived from (inherits from) an original chart `c1`.

How do I reset the colour encoding channel in `c2` back to nothing?

Here's a simplified example

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'],
    'b': [28, 55, 43, 91, 81, 53, 19, 87, 52]
})

c1 = alt.Chart(data).mark_bar().encode(
    x='a',
    y='b',
    color='a'
)

c2 = c1.mark_text().encode(
    text='a')

c1 + c2
```

The problem is I want `c2` to be a layer of black (not coloured) text labels.

I have tried the following options with no success:

```
c2 = c1.mark_text().encode(
    text='a',
    color=None
)

c2 = c1.mark_text().encode(
    text='a',
    color=alt.Color(field=None)
)

c2 = c1.mark_text().encode(
    text='a',
    color=alt.Undefined
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reset the colour encoding in `c2` using `alt.Undefined` as follows:

`c2.encoding.color = alt.Undefined`

Comment: since you found the solution yourself and shared it here, you can mark this as the accepted answer. That way, it won't show up as unanswered under the Altair tag.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution works. I'm adding another option for future viewers who might stumble upon this question wanting to specify colors. It is to explicitly specify the text to be "black" using `alt.value('black')` Admittedly, 'black' is not the same as "unsetting" the encoding, but it could be what someone wants for their plot.

```
c2 = c1.mark_text().encode(
    text='a',
    color=alt.value('black')
)
```